# Displaying pure html in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I playing with react-draft-wysiwyg editor. I progress quite well. But now I stuck how can I display the output of the editor.

For example, let suppose body is the output of the wysiwyg editor:

```
function ShowHtml(props) {
  let body = '<p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>'
  return (
    <div>
     {body}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the output will be exactly the same html with tags displayed without formatting.

```
<p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>
```

And I would like something like this:

> Sample text with **bold** and *italic*

In jQuery I would just set the html property of the div tag. But I do not know how to do it the proper way in React. Can I just grab a reference to the div and update it somehow just like in jQuery? Is it working with the virtual Dom?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to insert as an attribute dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body}}

```
  function ShowHtml(props) {
    let body = '<p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong></p>'
    return (
     <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body}} />
    )
  }
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Thanks, it was close but your answer was the first correct answer I think.

Comment: Is this okay to use in Production?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the double quotes, You can also setup the innerHTML dangerously:

```
   function ShowHtml(props) {
      let body = '<p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>'
      return (
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body}}>

       </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the double quote or if you wanna keep the double quote you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
function ShowHtml(props) {
  let body = '<p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>'
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body}}/>


  )
}
```

Comment: In reality body is the output of the editor. Do you have an idea how to convert an actual string to JSX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render html inside react components:

```
renderBodyContents = () => {
  return {__html: this.state.body}
}

...

render(){
  return(
    <p> dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderBodyContents()}></p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function ShowHtml() {
  return (
    <div>
     <p>Sample text with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.