# Display HTML on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React rich text editor which saves long description state as HTML text. I am trying to display the long description on product pages. How do I parse it for it is displaying the HTML text rather than converting it.

It's displaying like this rather than parsing and converting the HTML

```html
<p>hahahah baba is yellow <strong>kkkk very yellow</strong></p><p><strong>ichoo </strong></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying pure html in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401086/displaying-pure-html-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign this html to a variable and print by using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop.

eg

```js
const html = '<p>hahahah baba is yellow <strong>kkkk very yellow</strong></p><p><strong>ichoo </strong></p>';

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:html}}></div>
```

Comment: is dangerouslySetInnerHTML a package or ??

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not a package. dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM.

Comment: const [longdescription, setLongDescription] = useState([]);

  const html = { longdescription };


i then displayed it this way   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}></div>

 but its saying Type '{ longdescription: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: You are setting initial value of state as array.
Change useState([]) to useState('"") and const html = longdescription;

Comment: @CollinsJim You'll need to use your own thought processes to adapt the answer to your specific object model, since you didn't share that model in the question.

Answer (score 0):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<p>content...</p>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Example snippet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-matan-kzzydv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Type '{ __html: { longdescription: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ __html: string; }'.
  Types of property '__html' are incompatible.
    Type '{ longdescription: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.   am having this error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as mentioned in React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

I use  [react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html)  in my projects.

A sample code will look like this

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
 
renderHTML("<a class='github' href='https://github.com'><b>GitHub</b></a>")
```